Azure DevOps Services - Repository Count Limit?
My create new repository button in Azure DevOps Services has vanished.
Is there a limit to how many repos we can create in Azure DevOps Services?
Is there some other explanation as to why I cannot create any more repositories?
I own the ADO Services site, so its not that the owner has removed my permits.
I just don't see the button anymore.

There is no any docs to state the limitation on the max number of repositories in Azure DevOps. Have you checked whether the permission "Create repository" is "Allow" for you on Project Settings > Repositories > Security? As the organization owner, I cannot see the "+ New repository" button only when this permission is set to "Deny" for me.

As far as I know, there is no limit on the max number of repositories in each project of Azure DevOps. I also do not see any official documentation to state this.
For the issue you are facing, as discussed in above comment, you can go to Project Settings > Repositories > Security page to check and ensure the permission "Create repository" is "Allow" for you.
